# The session state is timeout in seconds, instead of minuntes

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net webform application is deployed and hosted in IIS.

I set 120 for the timeout of session state in Web.config.

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), the timeout is in minutes, but the session actually is timeout in 120 seconds. I did not understand this behavior. Do you konw the reason?

```
<system.web>
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="xxx" loginUrl="Error.aspx" protection="All" timeout="240"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
<globalization requestEncoding="Shift_JIS" responseEncoding="Shift_JIS" fileEncoding="Shift_JIS"/>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="1800"/>
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
```